# How to override adminhtml html file

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides, html

I need to overwrite the file **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/web/template/default-address.html**. I have tried creating a custom module and adding the file in **app/code/myvendor/mymodule/view/adminhtml/web/template/default-address.html** but it is not working.

I have also tried adding the file directly in **app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Magento_Customer/web/template** but it's not working either.

How can I overwrite html files from magento admin? I'm working in Magento 2.3.5 p-1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Create an Admin theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html) to override templates

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I could do this without creating a theme but I can see that I can't. With the theme it works perfectly.